# How should I manage default checkbox state

Tags: angular

I have a array of categories. I also have an array of checked categories.

`categories` contains all the categories

`categoriesSelected` contains all the category_id that should be checked

Here is the code:

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [id]="category.id"
        [checked]="categoriesSelected.findIndex(elem => { return elem.id === category.id }) ">

   <label class="custom-control-label" [for]="category.id">{{ category.name }} />
</div>
```

My idea is to check if the current id of category is found in `categoriesSelected` array and bind it the `checked` property

But it doesn't work.

Anyone knows how to fix it ?

Comment: I don't understand, you want to bind with `index` of the element? What happens when users checks or unchecks the checkbox?

Comment: try out answer , you should check for categoriesSelected  has value or not, with ? operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this , make use of [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
   <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [id]="category.id"
        [checked]="categoriesSelected?.includes(category.id) ">
   <label class="custom-control-label" [for]="category.id">{{ category.name }} />
</div>
```

this will work if `categoriesSelected` is initialized , before this for loop runs

Comment: thanks! it works great, I was looking for the includes function. Do you know where I could find some docs on all those fonctions, includes, map, filter, etc... ?

Comment: welcome...here only : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes ..and you can upvote my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the [checked] with isSelected method as follow:

```
<div *ngFor="let category of categories">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [id]="category.id"
         [checked]='isSelected(category.id)' />

  <label class="custom-control-label" [for]="category.id">{{ category.name}} </label>
</div>
```

TypeScript code:

```
isSelected(id) {
    let isFound = false;
    this.categoriesSelected.forEach((tempCategory) => {
      if (id === tempCategory.id) {
        isFound = true;
      }
    })
    return isFound;
  }
```

For better performance approach, you can set the 'categoriesSelected' to type HashSet, and check if the id contains the selected set as below:

```
categoriesSelected: Set<Category>;

// bind this method with the template [checked]='category'
isSelected(category) {
   return this.categoriesSelected.has(category);
}
```

Comment: categoriesSelected contains all the category_id , that means only includes function will do